# AngularJS. Add code to all partials inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

How can I add code inside ng-view once(not inside all partials)? I want to have global block which will append or prepend inside ng-view, where I can use scope from current controller.

Comment: ng-include will work "inside all partials" but that's not what you want, and you can place blocks outside of your ng-view but that will have no controller access,  so we're left with a sort of global controller setup or `ui-router`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-include` inside each template to include the same template in all parts.

Answer (score 0):

dunno know really what you want to do, but with the little info you gave, go to your index.html template and write the code you want to within a block element such as

```
<div class="your class name">
   ...
</div>
```

either before or after

```
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

depending on whether it's prepend or append. However, make sure you reference the controller properly.